# How does include work?

Tags: module, compiler-errors, include, ocaml, functor

I have

```
module type T = sig
    type t
end
```

and

```
module Make (TypeProvider : T) = struct
    include TypeProvider
    type d = Wrapped of t
end
```

and

```
module Test = struct
    include Make (struct type t = ForWrap end)
    let f = function | Wrapped ForWrap -> ()
end
```

I imagined Test after compilation like

```
module Test = struct
    type t = ForWrap
    type d = Wrapped of t
    let f = function | Wrapped ForWrap -> ()
end
```

But in real, it is not compilable code. OCaml says me:

```
module Test = struct
    include Make (struct type t = ForWrap end)
    let f = function | Wrapped ForWrap -> ()
                               ^^^^^^^
```

> Error: Unbound constructor ForWrap

```
end
```

And I cannot understand why.
What's the problem in my solution?

Comment: functor application is a runtime operation and you cannot treat ``include`` as a pure syntactic level replacement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see the signature of `Make (struct type t = ForWrapp end)`:

```
module M = Make(struct type t = ForWrapp end)
```

`ocamlc -c -i xxx.ml` shows you the signature of this module:

```
module M : sig 
  type t
  type d = Wrrapped of t
end
```

Note that the constructor `ForWrapp` is not available in the result module.  This is why your code does not type-check.

Why the constructor is gone?  This is since the functor `Make`'s argument signature is `T`.  `T` defines a type `t` which is abstract.  Even if you apply `Make` to a module with more detailed signature (here `struct type t = ForWrapp end`) it is coerced down to `T` and the constructor information is lost.